# Can ISPs learn customers ADSL modem brand?

Tags: isp, modem, adsl

Can ISPs learn customers ADSL modem brand by any means?

Comment: Given you've said "any means", if nothing else, they could have a highly trained team of hitmen and assassins break into your house to take a look at it.

Comment: That's a valid answer if there is any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be very difficult. They'll know the MAC address of the modem and since each manufacturer has their own unique OUI it would be a trivial matter to match your modem MAC address to the manfufacturer of the modem.

Answer (score 1):

They can get a good idea if they care enough to look. They can see your modem's mac address, which if not changed leads them to the manufacturer.